# What are the ramifications of open cannibalism?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Let's say that I'm about to engage in some good old-fashioned American cannibalism, but instead of `[Hidden]`, I see `[Detected]` on my HUD. If someone sees me engage in cannibalism, I know that the perk describes it as a "crime against humanity," but what does that actually mean? Do I lose reputation with the faction of the guy who sees me? Does he (and any other witnesses) turn hostile? What exactly happens?

Comment: In Fallout 3, any observers would turn hostile. I am not familiar enough with the differences in New Vegas to say what additional effects your "crime against humanity" might accrue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't resist trying this perk. I didn't opt for it in Fallout 3, so I can only speak of New Vegas.

If you drag a body to the corner where no one can see you, there are no problems. You gain health, gain rads, and lose a little karma.

If you do it in the open (while [Detected]), everyone turns hostile against you. But they forget soon enough... if you leave the town and come back, all is good. It won't change how a faction thinks of you.

It's the same thing as stealing from or killing a random person. Take out a leader... and there are problems. But otherwise, no biggie.

Comment: +1: Take out a leader... and there are problems. But otherwise, no biggie.

Comment: +1 for a right and well written answer.. but one thing to correct: eating corpses does not raise RADS.

Comment: Also, doing it in the open on The Strip doesn't affect anyone. I Dine and Dashed the McCaffery guy that the Atomic Wrangler wanted assassinated. Did it right in front of Gomorrah, and no one batted an eye.